# Django, polymorphism and N+1 queries problem

Tags: django, inheritance, orm, django-orm

I'm writing an app in Django where I'd like to make use of implicit inheritence when using ForeignKeys. As far as I'm concerned the only way to handle this nicely is to use `django_polymorphic` library (no single table inheritence in Django, WHY OH WHY??).

I'd like to know about the performance implications of this solution. What kind of joins are performed when doing polymorphic queries? Does it have to hit the database multiple times as compared to regular queries (the infamous N+1 queries problem)? The docs warn that "the type of queries that are performed aren't handled efficiently by the modern RDBMs"? However it doesn't really tell what those queries are. Any statistics, experiences would be really helpful.

**EDIT:**

Is there *any* way of retrieving a list of objects, each being an instance of its actual class with a constant number of queries ?? I thought this is what the aforementioned library does, however now I got confused and I'm not that certain anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've digged a little bit further and found this nice passage:

https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic/blob/master/DOCS.rst#performance-considerations

So happily this library does something reasonably sane. That's good to know.

Answer (score 2):

[Django-Typed-Models](https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models) is an alternative to Django-Polymorphic which takes a simple & clean approach to solving the single table inheritance issue. It works off a 'type' attribute which is added to your model. When you save it, the class is persisted into the 'type' attribute. At query time, the attribute is used to set the class of the resulting object.

It does what you expect query-wise (every object returned from a queryset is the downcasted class) without needing special syntax or the scary volume of code associated with Django-Polymorphic. And no extra database queries.

Answer (score 1):

In Django inherited models are internally represented through an `OneToOneField`. If you are using [`select_related()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in a query Django will follow a one to one relation forwards and backwards to include the referenced table with a join; so you wouldn't need to hit the database twice if you are using `select_related`.

Comment: Well right, but here I'd like to use an external library that attempts to return instances of actual classes for all the items in the relatioship. Therefore I imagine it performs some additional joins of all the tables in the hierarchy under the covers. And this is what I'm concerned with.

Comment: AFAIK django-polymorphic-models doesn't use `select_related()`, but you should be able to add it when retrieving a queryset with it, so you shouldn't have any additional database calls as well...

Comment: Well... the code is based on this snippet it seems: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/. And it unfortunately performs N+1 queries which is unacceptable in my case.